# Pointing dereference inside a struct error (indirection requires pointer operand)

Tags: c

the code below moves current2 one node too far from where I want to stop:

```
typedef struct  s_coo
{
    int     x;
    int     y;
    int     z;
    void    *next;
}              t_coo;

typedef struct  s_env
{
    void    *mlx;
    void    *win;
    t_coo   **head;
}               t_env;

int draw_map_y(t_env *e)
{
    t_coo   *current;
    t_coo   *current2;

    current = *(e->head);
    current2 = (*(e->head))->next;

    while (current2->y == 0)
        current2 = current2->next;
    return (0);
}
```

So I tried writing in the while loop:

```
while ((*(*current2))->next->y == 0)
```

instead of:

```
while (current2->y == 0)
```

But I get the error "indirection requires pointer operand". Can anybody explain me and tell me how I could write it the right way? I am pretty new to C. Thank you.

Comment: while (current2->y == 0) is OK, what else have you changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((*(*current2))->next->y == 0)
```

is incorrect. As error "indirection requires pointer operand" says, you can apply -> to pointer but you are doing it on (*(*current2)) which is wrong construct (`*current2` is object of type `struct s_coo` but what should second `*` on that structure object do?).

Solution:

```
while (((t_coo *)current2->next)->y == 0)
```

What `((t_coo *)current2->next)->y` means is

1. take void pointer `current2->next`
2. and treat it as pointer to `t_coo` (which is typedef on `struct s_coo`)
3. and then access `y` member on that casted pointer

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting "indirection requires pointer operand" is because you are de-referencing the pointer. 
Also next pointer is of type void*. You need to type cast it into known pointer type.
This should work,

```
while(((t_coo*)(current2->next))->y == 0)
```